# VBA Sort creates error using relative references but not absolute references

Tags: vba, sorting, runtime-error

I've run into the strangest error that has me stumped.  I'm sorting through VBA, and I want to use relative references such that I can effectively sort multiple areas of the spreadsheet at once.

Code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("I19"),                            
Order:=xlDescending

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort
.SetRange Range("a19:x29")
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```

Which works great.  However, if I add, above the code the line:

```
Dim CMVTopCell as Range
Set CMVTopCell = Range("I19")
```

I get Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed.  I should note that upon the final code looks like this:

```
Dim CMVTopCell as Range
Set CMVTopCell = Range("I19")
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range(CMVTopCell),                            
Order:=xlDescending

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options).Sort
.SetRange Range("a19:x29")
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: CMVTopCell is already a range, so you don't need to wrap it in `Range()`. Also, make sure to *qualify all your range references with a worksheet object* (eg. you can't define a key which is on a different sheet from the sorted range, which is what you're doing here if `Options` is not the active sheet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim sht as Worksheet
Dim CMVTopCell as Range

set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Options)
Set CMVTopCell = sht.Range("I19")
sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range(CMVTopCell), _
                      Order:=xlDescending

With sht.Sort
.SetRange sht.Range("a19:x29")
.Header = xlGuess
.MatchCase = False
.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
.SortMethod = xlPinYin
.Apply
End With
```